# Consulta SQL rango de fechas

Tags: sql, ms-access

Tengo una consulta para ejecutar en access, la quería sacar en sql.

Tengo una tabla llamada prueba que contiene los campos fecha e id, estoy intentando que me devuelva todos los registros comprendidos en entre el 12/01/2019 y 12/06/2019 y la ejecuta pero devuelve los campos vacíos, veis el error?:

```
SELECT Fecha, id FROM PRUEBA where 'fecha' BETWEEN '12/01/2019' AND '12/06/2019'
```

Comment: ¿Que quieres decir con "devuelve los campos vacíos"?

Comment: que se supone que en ese rango de fechas tengo datos pero no me muestra nada, solo los campos

Comment: El fecha lo tienes entre comillas

Comment: ¿El formato de las fechas no debería ser YYYY/MM/DD?

Comment: El campo Fecha no deberia ir entre comillas, tienes que poner `WHERE FECHA` ...

Comment: pero access si lo hago así me salta un pop up y me dice que introduzca un parametro

Comment: ¿Pero no has preguntado como hacerla en SQL?

Comment: No, la quiero hacer en Access desde la opción de SQL

Comment: El formato que tengo de fecha es dia/mes/año, no debería de tener problema

Comment: Puedes probar con Fecha sin comillas y las fechas, en lugar de comillas, almohadillas (#).

Comment: Como te ha indicado @Capt.Teach el campo Fecha debe ir sin entrecomillar y luego debes escribir el campo exactamente igual, primero le pones la f mayúscula y luego en minúscula, deben ser iguales.

Comment: Nada y me dice que introduzca valor del parametro... esto es cosa del access seguro...

SELECT * FROM Prueba where Fecha BETWEEN #01/01/2019# AND #01/02/2019#

Comment: La consulta debiera ser así: `SELECT Fecha, id FROM PRUEBA where fecha BETWEEN '2019/01/12' AND '2019/06/12'`, si hay datos en este rango, debiera funcionar. (1) quitamos comillas a `fecha`, sino estarías comparando una cadena `"fecha"` y no la columna. (2) El formato para indicar fechas es `yyyy/mm/dd` (ISO). (3) Cuidado con columnas que sean `datetime` y tengan una hora, el hasta del `between` no es inclusivo del día completo. Asumo que `fecha`  es efectivamente una fecha y no una cadena, aclaralo por las dudas.

Answer (score 0):

@Hermes,  para mi lo que te comenta Patricio, asegurate que los campos sean datetime y si es así por default tienes que meterle el formato en YYYY/MM/DD, a no ser que le hagas un convert en la consulta para que te lo cambie.

Con ponerlo en YYYY/MM/DD seguro que te lo soluciona.